# Differentiate MVC routing for {Controller}/parameter to {Controller}/{action}?param=myvalue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I must be able to deal with a route like this:
`MyController/ElementType`
For that purpose I've created a custom route like this:

```
  context.MapRoute(
                  "NameOfTheRoute",
                  "MyPath/{controller}/{elementType}",
                  new { controller = "Elements", action = "Create" }
                  );
```

And it works fine, the problem is when I have a route like 
`/MyPath/Elements/GetElementType?elementType=fire88`

`GetElementType` is a different action, but it goes to the `Create` action because of the custom route I declared before, how can I let know the routing they are different actions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the reason why it going to this route because you didn't define a `route` to handle `action`  so `MyPath/{controller}/{elementType}` means after the name of `controller` everything will be considered as `{elementType}` so
you have to create another another route which will handle `action`

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "MyPathRouteWithAction",
    "MyPath/{controller}/{action}/{elementType}",
    new {controller = "Elements", action = "Create"}
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "NameOfTheRoute",
    "MyPath/{controller}/{elementType}",
    new {controller = "Elements", action = "Create"}
);
```

the first `custom route` will handle `routs` like `/MyPath/Elements/GetElementType/fire88`

Comment: in my case the url is not `/MyPath/Elements/GetElementType/fire88`, is like `/MyPath/Elements/GetElementType?elementType=fire88`. What I've done for the moment is to create a the link that executes the action like this: ` <a href="GetElementType/@elementType">link 1</a>` and modify the `default` route, just changed `id` to `elementType` and now it's working but I'm not sure this is the best way...

Comment: @AlexGH you should use `<a href="@Url.Action("Elements", "GetElementType", new { elementType= "fire88" })">link 1</a>`
`

Comment: I was trying that way first : <a href="@Url.Action("Elements", "GetElementType", new { elementType= "fire88" })">link 1</a> but I was getting the url like these: `/MyPath/Elements/GetElementType?elementType=fire88` I probably didn't update correctly the browser because I tried again now and is working like that, thank you